# Beginner Scheme: Reversing the numbers in a list of numbers without using reverse

Tags: scheme, racket

Example: (reverse-list (list 1 2 3 4)) => 4321  Note: I am not allowed to use string->num or num->string or reverse.

so the list is consumed and the reverse number is created (not a list anymore)

I'm having trouble with the recursive logic.

```
(define (reverse-list lofd)
 (cond [(empty? lofd) empty]
       [else (+ (* (exp 10 (something that starts at 0 and adds one extra everytime))
                   (first lofd))
                (convert-to-decimal (rest lofd)))]))
```

My code starts and turns the first number into num1*10^0 and then adds the numbers that are recursed.

What I am having trouble with is how would I make it so that in the recursion the exponent is 10^0 and then goes up to 1, 2, 3... until the length of the list minus 1? Also is my logic/template right? Thank you!

Comment: Why are you doing arithmetic when you just want to reverse the order?

Comment: ... because technically he is trying to compute the polynomial `1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3` at `x=10`.  The fact that the numbers look "reversed" is a special case when `x=10`.  He may not _know_ that this is what he's doing, but it is.  :)

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do but I am unable to get it =(

Comment: If you try directly computing a sequence of exps, you'll find that you're going "against the grain" of the recursive solution.  That is, rather than directly do: `1 + 2*10^1 + 3*10^2 + 4*10^3`, the direct recursive solution to this will effectively compute  `1 + [10 * (2 + [10 * (3 + [10 * 4])])]`.  Just treat this as any other introductory recursive function that you've studied, and you'll solve it.  But don't try doing it via repeated computing of exps: it's actually _harder_ than the recursive solution, and it's actually doing much more work than necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Strong suggestion: follow the [Design Recipe for list structures](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html#%28part._ch~3adesign-lists%29) both in spirit and to the letter.  This problem is novel enough to you that you won't get it easily.  You need the extra support that the Design Recipe steps make you go through.

In this specific case, you *really* need a good suite of examples (test cases) to help you out, because a solution to this problem is not immediately obvious.  It's tricker because this function isn't from lists to lists: it's from lists to numbers, so you must have a strong suite to help you catch silly mistakes.

For example, what should?

```
(check-expect (reverse-list empty) <fill-me-in>)
```

be?  And should we even consider the empty list?  Is it a weird input?  Is it sensical?  Does the *contract* say that we have to deal with empty lists as input, or can we be guaranteed that it only accepts non-empty lists?  This is the sort of thing you need to resolve up front!  What you have right now in code can't certainly be right, because the type of your contract... well, you have not expressed a contract formally, but once you do, you'll see that the base case has to be different than what you've written so far.

In the cited link about the Design Recipe, part 5 is critical: once you have the template of your function, you need to understand what kind of thing the natural recursion is computing.  Use concrete test cases to help.  From looking at your code, it appears that you may have skipped this step, because the code you've written does not appear to consider the question: "What do the natural recursions compute?"

---

Concretely, if we're doing:

```
(reverse-list (list 1 2 3 4))
```

What do we want the answer to be?  You said it yourself:

```
(reverse-list (list 1 2 3 4))   ==>   4321
```

Consider what the *natural recursion* will be:

```
(reverse-list (list 2 3 4))
```

What's the value of this?  We know that it must be

```
(reverse-list (list 2 3 4))     ==>   432
```

Once you figure that out, ask yourself: does the value of the natural recursion have any relationship whatsoever to the answer of the original question?

Given that we're trying to solve:

```
(reverse-list (list 1 2 3 4))   ===>   4321
```

and we have the pieces `1` (the first part of the list) and `432` (from the natural recursion), can we put together `1` and `432` in some way to get `4321`?

---

Repeat this for a few examples.  And by few, I mean more than one.  :)  Do this concretely for those examples, and your brain will have a much better shot at pattern matching and generalizing to figure out what the code for the recursive case must be.

That is, once you've gotten enough exercise figuring out how to get the right answer for the concrete cases, go and see if you can express what you were doing with the concrete values back to the original terms in your program.  e.g. if you figured out that:

```
we want to get 4321 out of 1 and 432:
    => 1 + 10 * 432

...  other examples you worked out...
```

Let's re-express these in prefix notation:

```
we want to get 4321 out of 1 and 432:
    => (+ 1 (* 10 432))

...  other examples you worked out...
```

What parts are changing?  What parts are staying the same?  What does the first changing part stand for?  What does the second changing part stand for?  That is:

```
we want to get 4321 out of 1 and 432:
    => (+ 1 (* 10 432))

...  other examples you worked out ...

we want to get (reverse-list lst) out of (first lst) and (reverse-list (rest lst))
    ==> ???
```

Once you see the pattern, then you've figured out what the code *needs* to be for the recursive case.  But note that you truly need a suite of examples here: trying to generalize out of one specific example isn't enough for your brain to see patterns.  Your brain *requires* the repetition from working out multiple examples to be able to start seeing patterns.

Comment: So far I have 

(define (reverse-list lofd)
  (cond
    [(empty? lofd) 0]
    [else (+(*(exp 10 0) (first lofd))) (reverse-list (rest lofd))])) 

(check-expect(reverse-list empty) 0)        
(check-expect(reverse-list(list 1 2 3 4))4321)
But I still can't figure what to do with recursive part.

Comment: Please step away from the code.  You are not going to get anywhere with the `exp` stuff, and trying to "hack" it from a broken solution to a correct solution is not easy.  Follow the Design Recipe.

Comment: To be more specific: what's the value of `(reverse-list (list 2 3 4))`?

Comment: The value would be 432. do you mean natural recursion as in the empty list returning 0?

Comment: When I use the term _natural recursion_ for the problem `(reverse-list (list 1 2 3 4))`, I ask for: `(reverse-list (list 2 3 4))`.  Ok, so you know that `(reverse-list (list 2 3 4))` is 432.  You know that the answer of `(reverse-list (list 1 2 3 4))` is 4321.  Is there any numeric relationship between 1, 432, and 4321?

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't seem to find the relationship :(

Comment: If you had the numbers `1` and `432`, can you manipulate them in some way to get `4321`?  Consider multiplication and addition.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26418/discussion-between-james-lalonde-and-dyoo)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass along another parameter, besides the input list. If needed, create a new helper procedure (or an inner procedure, or a named `let`, etc.) for this to work. The two parameters will keep track of the current position in the list, and the current exponent of 10. Something along these lines:

```
(define (reverse-list lofd n)
  (cond [(empty? lofd) ; what do we return if the list is empty?
         <???>]        ; not the empty list! we're building a number
        [else          ; otherwise add this term, taking the
         (<???> <???>  ; current element times current 10^n and
            (reverse-list <???> <???>))])) ; advance recursion over lofd and n
```

Call the procedure with this initial values:

```
(reverse-list (list 1 2 3 4) 0)
=> 4321
```

Comment: Yeah, the solution is _significantly_ easier that the original author is thinking, but it is not obvious at first.  The recipe will pull him through.  :)

Comment: ... if he doesn't skip steps.  Gotta keep him to follow the steps till the solution is basically at his fingertips.  But it is actually neat how _relevant_ this particular problem is.  He probably doesn't realize it yet, but he's basically deriving from first principles the form of Horner's formula for evaluating polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Scheme solution; it uses stuff like null?, car and cdr which have historical importance but are not in your 'learning Racket' vocabulary.  Maybe it will illustrate an approach.

```
(define (list->reverse-number l)
  (if (null? l)
      0
      (+ (car l) (* 10 (list->reverse-number (cdr l)))))
```

If you insist on trying to use `expt` then you might try something like this (using named-let, which might be beyond your level):

```
(define (list->reverse-number l)
  (let reversing ((l l) (n 0))
    (if (null? l)
        0
        (+ (* (expt 10 n) (car l))
           (reversing (cdr l) (+ n 1))))))
```

but I've no idea if the above will work.  Actually, this works too.

Comment: I understand where this solution comes from however I'm stuck at where I wrote NOTE in my code. I need the code to replace NOTE as a number that goes from 0 to the length of lofd minus one for it to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

(define (reverse-number lofd)
  (cond
    [(empty? lofd) 0]
    [(not(empty? lofd)) (+ (*(expt 10 (NOTE)(first lofd)) (reverse-number (rest lofd)))]))

Comment: @JamesLalonde It should be clear from the answers you've got that the reason you're stuck is that there is nothing you can replace NOTE in your code with that gives you a solution - that path is a dead end.

Comment: @molbdnilo Actually, both versions in my answer work.  Try them.

Comment: @GoZoner I am aware of that, but none of them is OP's code with "NOTE" replaced by "something that goes from 0 ...", which is why I called OP's attempt a dead end.